# Can't upload application from Application Loader

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, itunes, monodevelop, provisioning

I finished work on an iPhone app in MonoDevelop and got a distribution provision from Apple. In the Release|iPhone build of MonoDevelop I set the 'Iphone App Bundle Signing' option to use the distribution user/provision and I built the app.

It created a .app in the bin/release folder. I tried uploading it using the application uploader but it wouldn't let me select the .app I had just built (it was greyed out)

Any ideas why that might happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the Application Loader only accepts zip files.  Have you zipped up your app bundle?

Answer (score 3):

Double Click 'Deliver your app', then you should be able to select the .ipa which is different than a template.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an .ipa file. take a look a this: [MonoTouch Enterprise - Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013637/monotouch-enterprise-deployment)