# How to deploy a MonoTouch application to a remote device

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

Here is our situation: We have the paid version of MonoTouch and we are registered with Apple for the Developer Enterprise program, so we won't be distributing our application via the Apple iStore. What I have done so far is to create the Provisioning Profile on the Apple developer site. I have set up the Provisioning Profile with Xcode and I am able to compile a signed version of our application and deploy it to my iPhone using MonoTouch. Now what I am needing to do is get the application on a colleagues iPhone. This iPhone has also been registered at the Apple site and is included in the Provisioning Profile. The problem is that the colleague is situated far from me and he does not have a Mac; he only has a Windows laptop. How do I go about sending him the application and what steps does he need to take to get it on his iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can do this http://forum.voxilla.com/rf-support-forum/install-ad-hoc-distribution-iphone-ipod-touch-application-33448.html

If i got the problem right.

Comment: Thanks, vkline, for the response. From this website it seems that all that is needed is the .app file and the provisioning profile and he can get the app on his iphone with iTunes. Ok. The only problem then is sending the .app... cos when I try send this with Skype I get the message that the .app is not a regular file but a bundle. Do i need to zip the app file or something to send it?

Comment: @BruceHill just zip it or rar it :)

Comment: @BruceHill Hope you saw that --> to create IPA Create a folder named Payload. Copy app.app into the Payload directory. Compress the Payload directory and rename the zip file to app.ipa.

Comment: The steps given in this link worked perfectly! :) Thanks, vkline.

Comment: try this one --> http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html @KirkWoll Sorry for the delay :)

Answer (score 1):

try this service - http://testflightapp.com/

----> to create IPA Create a folder named Payload. Copy app.app into the Payload directory. Compress the Payload directory and rename the zip file to app.ipa.

Comment: Ok. I will try this. But I see on the first page that it talks about dragging the IPA. Maybe this is a very noobie sort of question, but how do I create the IPA in MonoTouch?

Comment: this might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013637/monotouch-enterprise-deployment

Answer (score 0):

You should use OTA (on the air) distribution then, it will allow to install the application directly on the iPhone just by browsing to an url with safari
The process is described here: http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html !
If you are using Xcode 4, do almost the same : build and archive, then chose "share" and select "distribute for enterprise" and fill the needed fields!